# счетчик отсылки сообщений

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, counter

```
if right_car.size.positive?
     send_messages(user, filter)
   end
```

После `send_message` необходимо поставить счетчик, при том он должен обнуляться каждый день.

Как сделать привязку к дате, подскажите? Если счетчик можно просто `counter +=1`

Comment: Вам нужно хранить значения счётчика за предыдущие дни?

Comment: нет, не обязательно.

Comment: Храните в базе не только счётчик, но и дату. При обновлении счётчика проверяйте её и при необходимости обнуляйте счётчик и обновляйте дату